# React Native Image Cache Ignore the Query Params for Image URL

Tags: image, caching, react-native

In our react native project, we got the image url with the signing key append after the image url. Like `http://my_bucket.s3.amazon.com/my_profile.jpg?signing_key=I_am_changeable_every_time`.

We show the above url as following:

`<ImageView source={{ uri: photo.uri }} />`

We want to react native image component could handle the image cache for us. While the react native image component would load the image every time. One possible reason is that the react native image component does not really do any cache stuff.

Then we're trying to find some external [react-image-cache library](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-img-cache).

**But as my understanding, almost all the image cache library would treat the whole image url as the cache key. What should we do if our image has a signing_key param which would change over time**

We have thought using the **image_path** instead of the **image_full_url** or the image_id in our business context as the cache key. While we have not found any library which could give us this ability.

**My question is that: How can we handle the changeable image url cache, is there any library you recommended?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image). You can tell it to ignore the query params.

```
type ImageCacheManagerOptions = {
  headers: PropTypes.object,                      // an object to be used as the headers when sending the request for the url. default {}

  ttl: PropTypes.number,                          // the number of seconds each url will stay in the cache. default 2 weeks

  useQueryParamsInCacheKey: PropTypes.oneOfType([ // when handling a URL with query params, this indicates how it should be treated:
    PropTypes.bool,                               // if a bool value is given the whole query string will be used / ignored
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)           // if an array of strings is given, only these keys will be taken from the query string.
  ]),                                             // default false

  cacheLocation: PropTypes.string,                // the path to the root of the cache folder. default the device cache dir 

  allowSelfSignedSSL: PropTypes.bool,             // true to allow self signed SSL URLs to be downloaded. default false
};
```